# Removing nulls from Array in presto

Tags: presto, trino

I'm extracting data from a json column in presto and getting the output in a array like this [AL,null,NEW].The problem is i need to remove the null since the array has to be mapped another array.I tried several options but no luck.How can i remove the null and get only [AL,NEW] without unnesting?

Comment: Which presto version are you on?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`filter()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) for this:

```
SELEtrino> SELECT filter(ARRAY['AL',null,'NEW'], e -> e IS NOT NULL);
   _col0
-----------
 [AL, NEW]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Cool! Consider marking as accepted then :)

Answer (score 1):

If `array_agg` is the one creating an array with `NULL` elements you want to get rid of, a better approach could be [filtering during aggregation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation):

From:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(name)
```

To:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(name) FILTER (WHERE name IS NOT NULL)
```